# Display Tagged Value Window in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, window, add-in, enterprise-architect

I am working on Enterprise Architect through C# add-in. I need to display Tagged Values window automatically if an attribute is dropped on a element. This window also needs to be docked in the Repository.

I tried using Session.Repository.AddWindow() but it works only if I have an add-in window. Is there any EA API available to display Tagged Values window through code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised that the TaggedValue window has a shortcut you can access (ctrl+shift+6), so you can always simulate that input and the window should appear

If the window was part of a layout (and then removed) it will appear back where it should be

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer is no. The position is stored in the registry and the menu for loading different workspace layouts simply loads and stores these positions from `%appdata%\Sparx Systems\EA\Workspace Layouts*`. You can decode these and set positions for individual windows, but EA can only load them from a manual menu call. The only way (if you are forced to) is to simulate a menu click through Windoze back doors.

Comment: at that point if he has to simulate menu clicks, its better to just recreate a user control